# Using Airplay with Noise

Tags: music

Is there any way to connect my Airplay system to Noise? I know that I can make it work with XMMS2 through a plugin.

I have an AirPort Express which run perfectly with OSX 10.10 and Windows 10.

Comment: I'm assuming you have an AirPort Express not AirPlay Express (which I could not find anywhere), so I edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I found this solution for Ubuntu, which in theory should work in Freya too.*

First install some packages related to PulseAudio (a sound API used by elementary) by typing the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-raop pulseaudio-module-zeroconf paprefs
```

Then start the PulseAudio preferences by typing `paprefs` and check the two options under Network Access. [The window could look similar to this screenshot.](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-pNUxDzTpBgw/TWc9qmg-BqI/AAAAAAAABFQ/FRL7xQroHFs/s1600/paprefsNetwork.png)

Reboot your system.

Click on the sound indicator and open the sound settings ([example screenshot](http://oliverj.bplaced.net/img/elemos/settings_sound.png)). With a bit of luck you can now select your AirPlay device from the list of available outputs.

*Based on answer to ["Is there a way to stream audio/video to an Apple Airplay Device?"](https://askubuntu.com/a/438731/413066), created by StackExchange contributors.*

Comment: Sorry about the AirPlay mistake an thanks you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer above, and it would not work with my newer Airport Express.

After a lot of reading, it seems that newer devices use UDP rather than TCP. PulseAudio 11+ supports this, however as eOS is based on Ubuntu LTS, there is no easy way to achieve this without compiling a newer PulseAudio yourself.

I managed to compile and install PulseAudio 11.1 and use this rather than the system installed one. Details here:

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/Developer/PulseAudioFromGit/

The next problem is that Avahi and AirPort don't play well together. If you've enabled detection of AirPlay devices in paprefs, an incorrect IP beginning with 169.* is reported, and this causes playback to fail.

The solution is to disable auto detection in paprefs, and load the RAOP module manually in your `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` file, and specify your Airport's IP address.

See julien-gargot's reply here near the bottom:

https://github.com/hfujita/pulseaudio-raop2/issues/21

I used `encryption=none` option.

Everything now works fine, and I've had no issues! Looking forward to the day when Ubuntu and eOS support this stuff out of the box.

Arch based distros and I presume Fedora will already come with latest PulseAudio 11.1 installed, so you only need to perform the final step of loading RAOP manually.

Regards,

John